# How can I get VS Code to consistently show a Jupyter input request?

Tags: python, input, jupyter, user-input

For context: Just running something like:

```py
string = input("Input here:")
print(string)
```

works perfectly fine and produces the expected output, so it is not that VS Code never shows the input request.
However, when running a function calling input within another function, VS Code doesn't show the input request and therefore just keeps waiting for an input.

What might cause this? I saw posts about it being a settings problem, however these fixes didnt solve my problem.

Funnily enough, I only experience this issue in VS Code, running the exact same notebook both in Pycharm and the browser-based Jupyter version work perfectly fine.